# Is it possible to get explorer context menus for a specified file in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu

For a given file path, I want to get the explorer context menus of it and then display those items in my application. I have googled for a long time, But didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: some people voted to close this question as "unclear what you are asking", but this is a clear question. Although I am wondering why you want this, unless you want to write a customized explorer.

Comment: I wrote a launcher https://github.com/qianlifeng/wox, for searched files,  user should be able to select context menus inside program. This is why I want to get explorer context menus of a file. I want to display them in my program with a better user experience.

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is that the question and title do not match. The title says you want all the context menus, but the question says that you want the context menus for a specific file. The use of the plural ("the explorer context menus of it [the file]") is also confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The context menu is built from many locations in registry, reconstructing them in code is *possible*, but not a trivial task.

[ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) is freeware and supports commandline arguments that export the menu commands. You can give it a try.

Comment: I tried that, but it can't get the menus from Shell Extensions. It has the shexview, which only list shell extensions. So is it possible to read the context menus from that shell extension?